# Whats wrong displaying this image?

Tags: .net, winforms

```
PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
image.Image = new Bitmap("grass.jpg");
```

In my project, I added this image named grass.jpg.
This code throws this exception at run time: "Parameter is not valid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties of "grass.jpg" set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`. This will copy the image to the current directory of the program. The path "grass.jpg" is relative to the program, i.e. it is a file in the same directory as the program.

If you want to specify an absolute path to the image. You can use the path to the executable to build a path to the image like so:

```
string myDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
string imageFile = Path.Combine(myDirectory, "grass.jpg");
```

(But this is obviously the same path)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image couldn't be found. Try to specify a full path.